# how can i change the instance of a project #google-compute-engine

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have been using google-compute-engine for classes that I teach.  I recently deployed a website instance for a company that I work for.  That website has now been moved to production and I need to turn it over to a set of folks to manage.  I didn't plan well beforehand, and added the website to the same project which I use for my classes.  I have created a new project for the company site, but do not see a way to move the website from my classes project to my company one.  I dont want to have to delete and redeploy - is there a way for me to simply change or move the instance to the other project?  Both are in my account.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no direct way to transfer the VMs from one project to another. You can create a snapshot of your disk in project 1 and create an instance with that snapshot in project 2. One thing to note is that you will not be able to move the IPs between projects. You can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29585381/google-compute-engine-use-snapshot-from-another-project) for steps.